# jquery - 6 version jump broke backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Let me start out by saying that jquery is quite simply amazing. I have found it to be quite dependable and it certainly has made my life easier.

on to my issue..

I have a website that was using jquery 1.4.2
jQUery is currently at jquery-1.10.1.js

up till today I use jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js
the current version is jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js

Today i tried upgrading to the 1.10.1 verision and my page simply doesnt work. It looks like the ajax calls are not even working so i plan to start there.

The upgrade is spurred because I am abandoning .net menus as the viewState mechanism is too fragile once you start doing any sort of ajax. I have found a jquery menu example and it required 1.9.x.

My question is this

1. I am very surprised that my page doesnt work w/ the v1.10 version of jquery. I have been away a while. What is jquery's track record for maintaining backwards compatibility?
2. Are there any good articles that have been written concerning this topic.
3. Are there any tools that I might be able to take advantage of.
4. How do the jquery and jquery-ui versions relate? Am I good as long as I match the first two segments? For instance jqUI is 1.10.3 and jq is 1.10.1.
   ** I found this answer.
   each version of the api does reference the lowest version of jquery that is supported.
   example-  http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/

My current plan is to simply download all the intervening minor versions and test them 1 by 1. This could take a while... I'd rather be adding functionality.

Thanks. I know this is a bit of an oddball question. Any advice is appreciated.

Greg

I have read the readme's about what has been deprecated and i do not see mention of anything that I use. 
I do have things built in a way that it is very easy to included a specific jquery file.

Comment: jQuery's breaking change are pretty well documented in their change logs. Major changes have happened between `1.4` and `1.10`, especially at `1.9`.

Comment: i looked quite a bit before i posted a question. Can you point to an example. Im sure once Im in the right spot it will be the snake that should have bit me... but I aint yet bit...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are a number of items that have been deprecated, and removed. The `.live()` method is one such example. Is that what you meant by an example? Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: @CrazyTrain - If you will post an answer  i will mark it. I appreciate you taking the time to comment.

Comment: I think your answer should be fine. Just go ahead and accept that one. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have things working again.

Jquery' site does have a section that lists changes in each method. It just requires some digging.

http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/

version 1.5 and to a lesser extent version 1.6 included extensive changes to the implementation of the ajax method.

among these, not explicitly listed as a change in the doc, is that datatype:'text/html' is now just 'text'

this turned out to be the thing that caused me problems. A very easy fix once i had it pinned down.

For the sake of anyone else following behind me, the ajax method is now a little more strict about json inputs and outputs. That would be another place to look if things were working in 1.4 and not in later versions.

Thanks

greg